# Is there a risk that “get_input_entity()” of Telethon will also exceed telegram API limits (FloodWaitError) just like “get_entity()”？

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

If we request the telegram api through "get_entity('username')" function of telethon too many times, we will received a “punishment”：
**FloodWaitError: A wait of xxxxx seconds is required (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest).**

According to the [telethon documents](https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/advanced-usage/accessing-the-full-api.html), to avoid duplicated requests, we could use "get_input_entity()" for the first time , then we could use other function like "get_entity('username')", benefiting from the saved information in cache.

My questions are below:

1. if we use "get_input_entity()" too many times, do we get the same "FloodWaitError" like we using "get_entity()"? If so, what is an appropriate request interval for "get_input_entity()"?
2. what is an appropriate way to input many entities all at once? Currently, I just use a loop to get_input_entity() some usernames from a list one by one.
3. Also, after I get_input_entity() of some usernames and saved them in the cache. If I disconnect my client, do I need to get_input_entity() of them next time?

Thanks in advance for any helps!

Best,
Jacob

Comment: Updates: I tried to use get_input_entity() in a loop, sleep 2~3 seconds each loop. However, after I got around 170 channel_id and access_hash, I received the FloodWaitError again (40000+ seconds punishment...). Does anyone know the appropriate interval for request the get_input_entity()? Many thanks!

Comment: There is no known "appropriate interval". The only thing that is known is that you can act like a human to not get limited.

Comment: thanks for your comments! I know we can never know the specific official API limits. I just want to get some experience with the interval tested by someone else~ I have tested the "appropriate interval" three times these days. First time: sleep 2~3, second time: sleep 10~15, third time: sleep 15~20. The interesting thing is all of them give me "FloodWaitError" after I get_input_entity() around 180 group entities. I will continue to test with a larger time interval. Hope this information could help others.

Comment: Another test: request through get_input entity(), time sleep for 60~70 seconds each time. After getting 100 entities, time sleep for 600 seconds. However, still got FloodWaitError after I got around 180 entities. It seems that 180 may be the upper limit that can be obtained over a period... continue to do testing...

Answer (score 1):

I guess I know the answer through my testing:
Telegram has a [website](https://limits.tginfo.me/en) to describe its different kinds of limits.

"Username resolve limit (for both bots and user accounts) up to **200 usernames daily**" (See this picture)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D3AI.png)

The get_entity() and get_input_entity() function are actually doing the "username resolve". Thus, no matter what time interval we set to request the data, we can only get around 200 entities (groups/channels/users) per day. (in my testing, the upper limit is around 180 actually).

Thus, the suitable way to use get_input_entity() is to request around 180 entities every day. Until now, I guess the most doable way to improve the "request speed" is to apply for several different telegram APIs. Then, we could get 180 entities * the number of APIs every day.